# Get image from Drawable folder in bitmap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bitmap, xamarin.android

How can get image from drawable folder for **BitmapFactory.DecodeResource**.
i tried this.

img name image kept in drawable folder then this

```
 Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resource.Drawable.img,0);
```

but it's generate a error

> "Can not convert from int to Android.Content.Res.Resources"

Comment: I think your arguments are wrong because if you see the docs the first parameter is the resources and the sceond one is the id of the drawable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.bitmapfactory.decoderesource?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am able to get drawable image for bitmap decode resource.
I used this code.

```
string imagefileName = "imgimge.png";
                        // Remove the file extention from the image filename
                        imagefileName = imagefileName.Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "");

                        // Retrieving the local Resource ID from the name
                        int id = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(imagefileName).GetValue(null);

                        // Converting Drawable Resource to Bitmap
                        var originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.Resources, id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bitmap image =  BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Resources,Resource.Drawable.blankImage);

The first argument returns resource for the current context, followed by your image resource link (which should be located in the 'Resource' folder)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: OP is using an incorrect argument. The first argument  returns resource for the current context, followed by your image resource link (which should be located in the  'Resource' folder).

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it

Comment: It's been added.